# openstack network create command gives "The Keystone service is temporarily unavailable" and "The server is currently unavailable"

Tags: openstack, keystone, openstack-neutron

Currently, we are trying to setup neutron for our cloud server. Since everyone is new to this, we are struggling a bit. When we entered this command:

```
openstack network create  --share --external \
  --provider-physical-network provider \
  --provider-network-type flat provider
```

And it throws this error:

```
Error while executing command: HttpException: 503, The Keystone service is temporarily unavailable.: 503 Service Unavailable: The server is currently unavailable. Please try again at a later time.
```

We are following openstack docs guide to a T.

Does anyone know what causes this error and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably one of the most common error messages related to openstack. Have you searched it? Keystone, the authentication service of openstack, has to be reachable. It's an apache service, so look into keystone and apache logs and figure out why it's not running. Also double check if your neutron configs point to the right endpoint, check passwords etc. if other services can authenticate (e.g. glance).

Comment: I fixed it, it was a problem with MariaDB. When we updated it from 10.1 to 10.3, I couldn't access my DB, so when I fixed that error it works now.

Comment: Alright, maybe you can add that as an answer so others don't need to go through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, it was a problem with MariaDB. When we updated it from 10.1 to 10.3, I couldn't access my DB, so when I fixed that error it works now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29889235)